# image processing sdk to optimize document image?

Tags: image-processing, windows-phone-8.1, lumia-imaging-sdk

I wonder if there is any image processing sdk that can optimize the document photos you take with your phone camera so the document looks like scanned?(like what Evernote does with document photo and business card)

I know there's Lumia imaging sdk but it's not really designed for enhancing document images.

ps: the sdk should be able to work with windows phone

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the Lumia Imaging SDK there isn't a built-in "document" filter. You could achieve some success, especially on business card photos, with the `WhiteboardEnhancementFilter`, but most likely it won't fulfil all your needs.

You could try experimenting with creating a recipe for it on your own. Perhaps starting with `WhiteBalanceFilter` and then working your way from there? Take a look at Lumia.Imaging.Adjustments namespace for ideas what else you can include.

Best of luck and have fun experimenting!